# Pairs which are of the form AB / BA

Tags: vocabulary, difference, word

I need help with 实现 v.s. 现实 and 罪犯 v.s. 犯罪.

I find it hard to remember the distinction between these pairs which are of the form AB / BA. Can anyone help me grasp the underlying ideas/logic/feeling?

Also, I'd be interested in other similar pairs.

Comment: 互相／相互 Probably usage differences, only.

Comment: I have the same problem remembering which is the adjective and which is the verb between 适合 and 合适 :/

Comment: Related: [What examples highlight the distinction between 产生 and 生产, both meaning “to produce”?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36276/what-examples-highlight-the-distinction-between-%e4%ba%a7%e7%94%9f-and-%e7%94%9f%e4%ba%a7-both-meaning-to-prod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of them have a logic, but often you'll need some classical exposure to feel it. Querying a dictionary like MDBG with "罪*", "*罪", "犯*" and "*犯" will help you feel the pattern.

### 罪犯 / 犯罪

罪 : N (a crime)
犯 : V (to commit / offend)

V+N gives V (like in 吃饭、喝水、生气、……犯罪), therefore 犯罪 is literally "to commit a crime".

You can find several words in which 犯 as the second character means the person committing a crime:

- 共犯 : the accomplice
- 囚犯 : a prisoner
- 嫌犯 : a suspect+
  (and tons of others, war criminals, juvenile criminals etc)
  Knowing these few examples helped me remember that 罪犯 shares the same pattern.

### 实现 / 现实

For this one, I like to remember useful pairs, like 梦想与现实, dream and reality.
Ultimately, I prefer to think of it as a case of V+N vs N+V where 实现 means "to cause to be now" and 现实 means "the current fruit/result":
现 is never a verb in `现X` compounds, it's always an adjective (or noun with an adjectival role) having a meaning around the concept of "now" (modern, current etc).

Answer (score 3):

There're no underlying logic on those pairs you've mention.  It's just a coincidence that the 2 words can be used in form of AB/BA where both AB and BA *is* a word.  Note that in the examples, AB and BA have different meaning while there are some example that has the same meaning, such as:

油漆 / 漆油 (paint)
色彩 / 彩色 (arguable as 色彩=color while 彩色=color(ful))

I believe there are similar situation in English such as breakout / outbreak or overlay / layover.  It'll be easier for you to just forget the AB/BA format and remember them as separate words.

Answer (score 2):

## Specific cases

In the case of 犯罪 and 罪犯, note that 犯 often comes up in expressions related to committing some sort of transgression (e.g. 犯法, 犯错误), and that 罪 in isolation can refer to crime (e.g. 罪与罚). Thus, I can interpret 犯罪 as "committing a crime". (Note: I am not sure if on a linguistics-level, this is actually an appropriate interpretation.) I then simply remind myself that 罪犯 is not the correct term if I want to say "commit a crime", and I will not be surprised when I recall that it means "criminal". (In this case, it helps that I recall hearing 某人犯罪 and *not* 某人罪犯 on the news.)

I am terrible at remembering the difference between 现实 and 实现, and the meaning is close enough (reality v.s. to realise) that I have been lazy about it (since I am more likely to hear either term than to use it personally). If I were to seriously make myself remember which one is the verb, and which the noun, I would probably make myself write out sentences, ideally where the terms appear together (e.g. 实现这个现实). Moreover, I would also rely on the fact that I can remember the phrase 现实世界 ("real world", or more loosely "world of reality", possibly a "contraction" of 现实的世界) without "corrupting" 现实 into 实现.

## General comments

**There is no real "underlying logic" that explains the different meanings that are achieved in cases where characters can be "flipped" or where their order can be reversed.** It is best to memorise the terms separately.

**In some cases, noting how the character order affects meaning *may* be useful. (This might take some maturity in or familiarity with Chinese; there's no one-size-fits-all standard to this.)** For example, in 开放, the emphasis feels like 开 to me, which fits the meaning of roughly "to open", whereas in 放开, the emphasis is on 放, which fits the meaning of "to let go".

There is a list of some more such character pairs [here](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/175525464598185724.html).

Answer (score -1):

- 我实现了我的梦想，I achieved my dream
- 现实 reality
- You can say 我实现了我的梦想，我的梦想变成了现实。I realized my dream,my dream has become realized.
- A man who 犯罪,thence become a 罪犯

Answer (score -1):

Crime(犯罪) is a behavior。 the criminal（罪犯） is a group of people. Only when people commit crimes(犯罪) can they become criminals（罪犯）!