# What examples highlight the distinction between 产生 and 生产, both meaning "to produce"?

Tags: difference

#### [产生](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BA%A7%E7%94%9F) (chǎnshēng)

> 病毒是怎样**产生**的?<sup>[[src]](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/128324492.html)</sup>
> How are viruses produced
>
> 导体中就会**产生**电流<sup>[[src]](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%94%B5%E7%9A%84%E4%BA%A7%E7%94%9F%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/19479932)</sup>
> [The] conductor will produce electric current.

#### [生产](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%94%9F%E4%BA%A7) (shēngchǎn)

> 操作人员对自己**生产**的产品要做到自检<sup>[[src]](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%94%9F%E4%BA%A7%E7%8E%B0%E5%9C%BA%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86/6789461)</sup>
> workers regarding their own produced goods need to perform self-checks
>
> 巧克力可用于**生产**时增加体力，红糖是产后补血之用<sup>[[src]](https://baike.pcbaby.com.cn/qzbd/1217835.html)</sup>
> chocolate can be used <s>to produce increased</s> during labor to increase physical strength, brown sugar is used postnatally to increase blood

(I originally mistranslated the above sentence; see [fefe's answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36278/8099).)

They are both verbs meaning "to produce" or something like this.  However, I can barely find a difference.  My impression is that 产生 is bit more general than 生产, where 生产 is better used for factories and companies.

I feel fairly sure there's some distinction here I'm missing...

**Question**: What examples highlight the distinction between 产生 and 生产?

I'm looking not just for random examples, but examples where switching from 产生 to 生产 makes a meaningful difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

生产 refers to human kind activities; i.e. to *produce* / *manufacture* / *make* / *create* (as the effect of human subject will).

产生 refers to natural activities; i.e. *generate* / *come into being* (as the effect of some kind process).

As a side note 生产 could mean *parturition* too.

As the examples you've showed,

> 病毒是怎样产生的?
>   导体中就会产生电流

Both 产生 are used for the context not containing subjective initiative, especially the intent of *to make* / *create*.

> 操作人员对自己生产的产品要做到自检

生产 is used for the intent of human kind activities, i.e. *manufactured* by the operator.

> 巧克力可用于生产时增加体力，红糖是产后补血之用

生产 means *parturition* here.

Comment: It's quite difficult to explain as non-native English speaker... Tell me if it's confusing.

Comment: Would it be possible to add examples please?

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Your examples seem enough; I tried to add some additional explanations.

Answer (score 4):

From [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/produce), to produce has the following two meanings:

> 1. To produce something means to cause it to happen.
> 2. If you produce something, you make or create it.

The first is 产生 and the second is 生产.

And for your last example:

> 巧克力可用于生产时增加体力，红糖是产后补血之用[src]
>
> chocolate can be used to produce increased physical strength, brown sugar is used postnatally to increase blood

The translation is wrong. Here "生产" means to give birth to a child, so the translation should be: "Chocolate can be used to increase physical strength during labor, ...."

Answer (score 3):

songyuanyao's answer pretty much sum up the difference between the two terms, I would like to add some examples.

生产 = [**manufacture**; produce] (by human with intention)

产生 = [**generate**; cause; create; produce] (naturally or unintentionally)

Example:

> 人类[**生产**]的机器无法对抗天灾[**产生**]的力量
>
> Human [produced/ **manufactured**] machines cannot fight natural disasters [produced/ **generated**] forces

~

> [**生产**]水泥所[**产生**]的污染
>
> Pollution [caused/ **created**/ produced] from [producing/ **manufacturing**] cement

Comment: Consider this. 這項計畫將產生極高的效益。 in English: This program can generate extremely high degree of benefit.

Answer (score 3):

It has to have the **cause/condition** to 产生 something, while we **develop tools and procedures** to 生产 something. 生产 can also mean *to give birth* along the same lines.

> 氧气和氢气经过化学反应可以产生水。// 氧气，氢气，经过化学反应 are conditions
>
> 这家公司生产食品 // 公司 has production lines with all the tools and procedures to 生产 food.

Answer (score 2):

An example where switching from 产生 to 生产 makes a meaningful difference:-

我们公司最近生产的产品将会产生影响到公司未来的收益:-

我们公司   ---  our Company's

最近生产的产品  ---  recently manufactured product(s)

将会   ---  would

产生影响到   ---  produce / make an impact

公司未来的收益   --- on the Company's future income.

Perhaps someone would like to improve on this?

Comment: The sentence would be better if you remove the “产生"

Comment: @fete -- yes, but I want both  产生 and 生产 in the same sentence to show the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

In Taiwan 生產 means:

Give birth. For example: 這個女生，在今年六月的時候生產。 in English: This female gave birth on June this year.

Produce somethings for usage of human activity.
for example: 這家公司，生產了3000劑的疫苗。 in English: This company produced 3000 doses of vaccine.

產生 means:

Give birth.(archaic)

Become exist. For example: 產生糾紛 in English: Conflict occurred.

Reference: [產生](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000123019) [生產](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000132465)

Comment: Could you add some examples that highlight the distinction please?

Comment: @Becky 李蓓 Added

Answer (score 0):

与人工制作相关的生产这个词，其他的是产生。example:工厂生产汽车。

Answer (score 0):

When you use "生产", there should be a conceptual "factory" that makes things on a massive scale. The kernel meaning of this word lies on "产", which means "giving birth to" or "being the source of" in Chinese. Typical usage of "产" includes: 母猪产仔了(A sow just gave birth to babies)；浙江产茶叶(Zhejiang Province produces tea)；被病毒感染的细胞生产了更多的病毒(The virus-infected cell produces more viruses)；核电站生产了大量的电能(The nucleic power plant produces much electric power)。

When you use "产生", it leads to some results. In English, "yield" is the counterpart word. The kernel meaning of this word lies on "生", which means "genesis of something" in Chinese. For instance, 肿胀产生了更强的痛感（The swelling yields increased pain）.When you use "产生", a hidden "XXX使得YYY产生ZZZ" structure is actually implied in the sentence, you should try to find what are the XXX, YYY, and ZZZ. In the case, XXX is 肿胀, YYY is (the patient), ZZZ is 更强的痛感。